# curl PUT request response info not showing

Tags: http, curl, put

I build curl request with PUT request and with json request payload. I wanna see response headers and payload, I added -I arg, when sending request.My curl request :

```
curl -I -X PUT http://localhost:8080/v1/test -H 'X-RequestId:test' -H 'key:test' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"status\":\"APPROVE\",\"rules\":null}"
```

But it showing me warning like this:

```
Warning: You can only select one HTTP request method! You asked for both POST 
Warning: (-d, --data) and HEAD (-I, --head).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `curl` man page:

```
-I, --head
              (HTTP FTP FILE) Fetch the headers only! HTTP-servers feature the
              command HEAD which this uses to get nothing but the header of  a
              document.  When  used  on an FTP or FILE file, curl displays the
              file size and last modification time only.
```

The `-I` option automatically issues http request with `HEAD` method, and this is what the error message is saying. By using `-d, --data` with `-I` the `curl` doesn't know which http method to use, because first one uses `POST` method implicitly and the second one uses `HEAD`. Which is basically what the error message says: `You can only select one HTTP request method!`

What you probably want is lower case `-i` option instead:

```
-i, --include
              Include the HTTP response headers in the output.  The  HTTP  re‐
              sponse  headers  can  include  things like server name, cookies,
              date of the document, HTTP version and more...

              To view the request headers, consider the -v, --verbose option.
```

Or use `-v` option to view both request and response headers.

Comment: It is actually `-I` + `-d` that cause the error message.

Comment: @DanielStenberg thank you for pointing it out, I edited answer to reflect that. I replaced `-X PUT` with `-d, --data` and rephrased the sentence a little bit.